# Using a column in a CTE that does not exist in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am new to writing recursive queries and I am trying to write my first one. I am trying to determine levels of a corporate hierarchy and have the result table include two columns- the consultant ID and the level that has been determined by the recursive query. In the CTE, I can't figure out how to reference "level" since it is a column that doesn't yet exist in a table. What am I doing wrong?

```
WITH consultantsandlevels
    (c."ConsultantDisplayID",
    consultantsandlevels."level"
    )

AS
(

SELECT c."ConsultantDisplayID",
    0

FROM flight_export_consultant AS c

WHERE c."ParentPersonDisplayID" IS NULL

UNION all

SELECT c."ConsultantDisplayID",

    c."ParentPersonDisplayID",

    consultantsandlevels."level" + 1
FROM flight_export_consultant

JOIN consultantsandlevels ON c."ParentPersonDisplayID" = consultantsandlevels."ConsultantDisplayID"
)

SELECT *

FROM consultantsandlevels;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
WITH RECURSIVE consultantsandlevels(ConsultantDisplayID, level) AS (
    SELECT "ConsultantDisplayID", 0 
    FROM flight_export_consultant 
    WHERE "ParentPersonDisplayID" IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fec."ConsultantDisplayID", cal.level + 1
    FROM flight_export_consultant fec
    INNER JOIN consultantsandlevels cal 
        ON fec."ParentPersonDisplayID" = cal.ConsultantDisplayID
)
SELECT * FROM consultantsandlevels;
```

Rationale:

- The `WITH` clause must start with keyword `RECURSIVE`
- The declaration of the comon-table-expression just enumerates the column names (no table prefix should appear there).
- The `level` is initially set to `0`, and you can then increment it at each iteration by refering to corresponding common-table-expression column.
- Queries on both sides of `UNION ALL` must return the same count of columns (that correspond to the declaration of the cte) with corresponding datatypes.

Comment: The top of the union has two columns (which fits with the column list in the CTE definition), but the bottom has three columns. Something is up.

Comment: @GMB I am getting this error now: ERROR: relation "consultantsandlevels" does not exist Detail: There is a WITH item named "consultantsandlevels", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. Hint: Use WITH RECURSIVE, or re-order the WITH items to remove forward references.

Comment: I am using postgresql if that makes a difference

Comment: @ekeckeisen: my bad, the `RECURSIVE` keyword was missing. Fixed.